# Why ternary not ternal?

Tags: etymology, terminology, mathematics

Why is is the base-2 numeral system called binary, the base-3 one called ternary, when base-8 is octal and base-10 is decimal?

The different suffixes, *-ary* vs *-al*, are what I am concerned about.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=binary

Comment: If *binary*, *ternary* and *decimal* were English words 400+ years ago (though possibly with slightly different meanings) then people producing new words were free to adapt the previous models and see which ones others were prepared to use. It is similar to Shakespeare inventing *fashionable* and *dispunge*  based on existing words, but only one of those is in current use.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems) provides a list of numeral systems and says:

> The common names are **derived somewhat arbitrarily** ***from a mix of Latin and Greek***, in some cases including roots from both languages within a single name[***hexadecimal***, for example]. There have been some proposals for standardisation.[*Multiplication Tables of Various Bases*, p. 45, Michael Thomas de Vlieger, Dozenal Society of America]

***Decimal*** is probably one of the earliest and [most commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=binary%2C%20ternary%2C%20decimal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), which may have influenced the passage from -ary to -al:

> c. 1600, "pertaining to a tenth or ten," from Medieval Latin ***decimalis*** "of tithes or tenths," from Latin *decimus* "tenth," from *decem* "ten" (from PIE root *dekm- "ten"). Applied to Arabic notation before modern use in reference to ***decimal fractions*** (fraction whose denominator is a power of 10) emerged 1610s. ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=decimal))

Comment: Apparently both _-al_ and _-ary_ are from latin

Comment: Yes, but the formation of the names of the numeral systems was _arbitrary_ using Latin or Greek _**roots**_.